# Showing A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xb4 in tid 11844 in WebView

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, webview

I am creating a browser and provided search option in which user can search list of strings

I am using below code to find it one by one in loop

```
webView.setFindListener((activeMatchOrdinal, numberOfMatches, isDoneCounting) ->{}


 webView.findAllAsync(contentKeys.get(contentNumber));
```

when I am using this function in high end devices it works perfectly
but when I am trying in row RAM devices, It crashes with below error.

```
 A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xb4 in tid 11844
```

OR

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x25cc48f7 in tid 12189
```

[image]
I have tried multiple solutions from StackOverflow but nothing worked

Thanks in advance

Comment: That means something in your code caused a C library to access an illegal address.  Likely by passing it a null variable, based on the low address.  Beyond that, we can't help-  you haven't given us any information for further debugging.

Comment: I am using these functions only, what more info I can share? please let me know

Comment: The full crash log for a start. You're assuming it was caused by the webview, but nothing you posted tells us that.

Comment: A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xb4 in tid 11844 
This only I get in crash log, nothing else

Comment: Its never just that.  There's always a full crash dump below it.  It doesn't look like a Java dump, but its always there.  If you can't see it, turn off your filters in logcat

Comment: I have updated screenshot in question

Answer (score 1):

For me, this happened due to a memory leak when navigating to a `WebView`-only screen from a screen that had embedded `WebViews`. The navigation animation was the reason for the memory leak. The following solved my issue:

```
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{animation: "none"}}> //for react-navigation v6
...
</Stack.Navigator>
```

For other React Navigation versions, it may be different. Be sure to check the [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/) before you paste the above code.

Source: https://github.com/LonelyCpp/react-native-youtube-iframe/issues/101#issuecomment-768052900

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I must find the `Memory Leak` in my fragment!

I used `profiler` of `android studio` and I find it finally from getting data from the *database*.

be aware of `Memory Leak`!

happy coding :)

Answer (score -2):

`Add` these two lines to your `build.gradle` in the `android` section:

```
android{
    compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility 1.8
            targetCompatibility 1.8
        }
}
```